# Integration test for PUT method returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing, put

I have been trying to write a test for a PUT method, but I can't seem to figure out why the actual result code is 400 Bad Request instead of 200 Ok.
This is my test:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = AgencyController.class)
public class AgencyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private AgencyService agencyService;

    @MockBean
    private AgencyMapper agencyMapper;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Update agency-happy")
    public void updateAgency() throws Exception {
        Agency agency = new Agency();
        agency.setId(1);
        agency.setName("Agency");
        agency.setEmail("agency@gmail.com");

        doReturn(Collections.singletonList(agency)).when(agencyService).getAll();

        agency.setName("Updated name");
        agency.setEmail("updated@gmail.com");

        when(agencyService.updatePartialDto(agency, agency.getId())).thenReturn(agency);

        mockMvc.perform(put("/agencies/editAgency/" + agency.getId())
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());

    }
}
```

And this is my method in the agency controller:

```
  @PutMapping("/editAgency/{id}")
    public Agency updatePartial(@RequestBody AgencyDto agencyDto, @PathVariable Integer id) {
        Agency mappedAgency = mapper.mapToEntity(agencyDto);
        return service.updatePartialDto(mappedAgency, id);
    }
```

I've tried debugging the test and expected vs actual returns 200 vs 400. The test seems to be fine until it hits the line with `mockMvc.perform()`. When stepping into the function, it finally comes to a point where it hits the method

```
public int getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
```

from `MockHttpServletResponse.class` and here it returns 400.
The `getAll()` method from the service is just a call to JpaRepository's `findAll()` method.
What have I done wrong? I also searched for examples, but I didn't find anything relatable.
Error:

```
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
    at com.project.controller.AgencyControllerTest.updateAgency(AgencyControllerTest.java:155)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
```

Comment: I don't see your requestbody in your test

Comment: What requestbody do you mean? I passed the object agency to my method call in `agencyService.updatePartialDto()`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following `ResultHandler` after performing a request on `MockMvc`. It will then print out more detail which includes the exception type that causes 400 :

```java
  mockMvc.perform(put("/agencies/editAgency/" + agency.getId())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
```

Such information should give you more insight about the root cause.

Comment: I updated the question with the error output

Comment: this is not what i mean. I tell you to add `.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());` , and update me what does it print out after that . thanks.

Comment: But where should I see the output from `.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());` ? I added this line but the output doesn't change and when trying to debug, the method breaks one line before, so the debugger doesn't even reach this line.

Comment: it will just output something to the console.....

Comment: the output is the same whether I add `.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());` or not